# Accessing global application state inside a custom Handlebars helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

In an ember.js application, I'm looking for an elegant way to access global application state (e.g. configuration/session data, information about the logged in user, ect) from within a custom handlebars helper. This is easy to do in routes/controllers using `Ember.Application.initializer` like so:

```
App.initializer({
    name: 'registerSession',
    initialize: function(container, application) {
        application.register(
            'app:session', 
            Ember.Object.extend({userId: 1, dateFormat:"MMMM Do, YYYY", /* ... */}), 
            {singleton: true}
        );

        application.inject('controller', 'session', 'app:session');
        application.inject('route', 'session', 'app:session');
    }
});
```

However there doesn't seem to be any equivalent of this in the Handlebars helper registration api, where you can essentially inject an external dependency.

My use case for example, is that the session data holds the user's date format preference, and I have a custom helper, `formatDate` where I want to be able to pull in their settings to use as the default format, eg:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('formatDate', function(timestamp) {
    //need to be able to access the global session data here
    //in order to get the user's date format preference
    return moment.unix(timestamp).format(session.dateFormat);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can if you use **Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper** which bring different function parameters. Once, you get the container you could look for any registered instance like your session.

I have not tested, but I think something similar to this example must work:

```
import {handlebarsGet} from "ember-handlebars/ext";

registerHelper('formatDate', function(value, options) {

      var container = options.data.keywords.controller.container;
      var session = container.lookup('app:session');

      var propertyValue;
      if ( options.types[0] !== 'STRING' ) {
         var context = (options.contexts && options.contexts.length) ? options.contexts[0] : this;
         propertyValue = handlebarsGet(context, value, options);
      } else {
         propertyValue = value;
      }

      return moment.unix(propertyValue).format(session.dateFormat);

    });
```

Take in consideration that helpers created with this method will not re-render their content when data changes. If you need to define a "bound helper", take a look at [Ember Handlebars Helpers](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/tree/master/packages_es6/ember-handlebars/lib/helpers).

Comment: ah this works perfectly! And it looks like bound helpers can be created with access to the same parameters/options data via [Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_registerBoundHelper).

Comment: Using the container in this manner is an antipattern.  Using it like  this you might as well define a global property and skip using the container all together.

Answer (score 1):

Helpers are isolated (like components), You'll need to pass in any external dependencies needed in order to use them.

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('formatDate', function(timestamp, format) {
    //need to be able to access the global session data here
    //in order to get the user's date format preference
    return moment.unix(timestamp).format(format);
});
```

Comment: Yeah thats what I was afraid of, as it means I will need to pass in that same configuration data everytime that i use the helper, `{{formatDate timestamp session.dateFormat}}` which isn't very DRY imo, but I guess I don't have any other options in this regard.

Comment: I switched the accepted answer to ppcano's answer, as it seems to work and solves my needs in this situation. However I do understand the reasoning behind and benefits of completely isolated helpers.